# PDO insert BindParam mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to use an array in the BindParam();?
i mean like this:

```
$stmt = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name,age) VALUES (:name,:age)");
$stmt->BindParam(array(":name"=>"michael",
                       ":age"=>"21"
                 ));
$stmt->execute();
```

OR
Do you have to bind them 1 by 1 like:

```
$stmt->BindParam(":name","Michael");
$stmt->BindParam(":age","21");
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: One by one I believe, but you can use just an array by removing the bindParam's and putting the array in the execute. See the [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) docs for examples.

Comment: Did you try it? what did it throw back?

Comment: Yes i know, that but i am concern about the security, when doing that? :)

Comment: Funky fort, i can try it out real quick, hang on :)

Comment: @MichaelJørgensen passing an array into execute is just the same as using bindParam so you'd be good security wise

Comment: Warning: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use an array with bindParam. In these cases, it is best to refer to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

However, you can use an array with [execute](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
$stmt = $this->Db->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name,age) VALUES (:name,:age)");
$stmt->execute(array(":name"=>"michael",
                     ":age"=>"21"
               ));
```

Comment: Yes i know and some other guy just told me, that the security is the same. I'll mark this as correct answer, many thanks once again :)